# Flutter - iOS - Offer codes unable to test

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

right now, we are implementing Offer codes for iOS. We are using Flutter for app.

Problem now is, that we are unable to test app. When I try to redeem code (by pure link or by "presentCodeRedemptionSheet()"), app always say we need install app (from App Store). When we install it, it overwrite debug version.

Does anybody meet this problem? Can somebody advice me how to proceed this?

Thank you.

Comment: I searching for information, but it seems, that it's impossible to test them for now.